# Exibição de imagens por meio de URL Mysql Php

Tags: php, html, imagem, bootstrap

não foi por falta de tentativa mas estou tendo problemas em uma coisa que acho que pode ser considerada simples. Bom o projeto é um site certo? Ele vai ser um site de consulta de mercadorias e somente. Eu criei uma pagina de Registro dos produtos.
    
    
    Cadastro

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "produtos";
$conexao = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($banco) or die(mysql_error());


$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$especificacoes=$_POST['especificacoes'];
$preco=$_POST['preco'];
$url=$_POST['url'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cadastro(nome,especificacoes,preco,url)
VALUES('$nome', '$especificacoes','$preco','$url')");
echo "feito";
```

Nesta pagina o cadastro esta sendo feito com sucesso. Porem eu não sei como exibir ele pela ID(Nota que todo produto registrado tem ID auto incrementante), eu gostaria de exibir estas imagens em quadradinhos no código.

```
<div class="thumbnail"><!--Centraliza a imagem dentro do box-->
  <img src="Aqui seria a imagem cadastrada" alt="ibagem">
  <div class="caption"><!--Esta div cria o que esta escrito abaixo da imagem-->
    <h3 align="Center">Aqui o nome cadastrado do produto</h3>
    <p align="center">E aqui as especificações cadastradas do produto</p>
    <p align="center"> <a href="produtos.html" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Especificações</a></p>
```

Porem eu não faço a minima ideia de como fazer isto ou de como fazer a ID 1 aparecer ao lado da ID 2 ao lado da ID 3, se alguem conseguir me ajudar eu agradeceria muito.

E me desculpem se estou postando errado, ou se esta pergunta já foi respondida, mas eu não consigo achar e depois de quase dois meses de procuras e só achando soluções como programas exteriores (como wordpress), não sabia mais onde recorrer.

Comment: Você já tem uma query que insere os dados, agora você precisa de uma para pegar os valores... `SELECT`, e depois um `while`... Não vou conseguir postar nada agora, se ninguém o fizer na volta eu faço...Qual o nome da coluna que contém os `IDs` ?

Comment: O nome da coluna é id

Comment: Eu consegui usar o select ... Só que não estou conseguido transformar a url em imagem... E agora to o negócio do while. Pelo que entendi eu vou colocar while id > x ai vou fazer id++ algo assim vlw pelo norte cara.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente tome cuidado como está fazendo essa inserção no banco. Utilize o [bind do PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) para evitar SQL Injection.

Uma vez inseridas as **informações** no banco de dados, através de um select você consegue resgatar os produtos na ordem que desejar. O default é por ID crescente, igual o que você quer.

Agora quanto as **imagens**, precisa ter uma lógica para relacioná-las com as informações no banco. Um exemplo bem básico seria a pasta com o ID do produto ter as imagens dele. Exemplo de estrutura de arquivos:

```
/imagens
  /produtos
    /1  ~> produto de ID 1
      foto1.jpg
      foto2.jpg
    /2  ~> produto de ID 2
      foto1.jpg
      foto2.jpg
    ...
```

Assim um exemplo de código onde você listaria os produtos seria:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "produtos";
$conexao = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($banco) or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("select * from cadastro order by id asc");

?>

<?php while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)): ?>

    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="imagens/produtos/<?php echo $produto["id"]; ?>/foto1.jpg" alt="<?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?>" />
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 align="Center"><?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?></h3>
            <p align="center"><?php echo $produto["especificacoes"]; ?></p>
            <p align="center"><a href="produtos.html" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Especificações</a></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Não testei, pode ter algum erro de sintaxe mas espero ter passado a ideia geral.

OBS: Para ter essas imagens nas pastas dinamicamente, você precisaria fazer o upload das imagens no momento do cadastro.

Comment: Então cara olha o que fiz
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $img = $row["url"];
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<div class='col-sm-3 col-md-4'>";
    echo "<div class='thumbnail'>";
    echo "<img src='" . $row["url"] . "'" . "alt='Oi'>";
    echo "<div class='caption'>";
    echo "<h3 align='Center'>" . $row["nome"] . "</h3>";
    echo "<p align='center'>" . $row["especificacoes"] . "</p>";
    echo "<p align='center'> <a href='#' class='btn btn-default' role='button'>Especificações</a></p>";
Esta funcionando mas a segurança ñ.